# How do you clear a combo box in VB when pulling information from a database?

Tags: sql, vb.net

We are writing a program that pulls a Teacher from a database, then you select the "period" 1 - 7. What is happening is if we pick period 1 on teacher john doe. Then when you pick another teacher it doesn't clear the period that we selected before. How do we clear this information every time we select a different teacher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with VB, but this isn't really database related. What you need to do is listen for the event of the user selecting a teacher. Then in the code handling that event, clear the period selection.

[Events and Event Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2z7x8ys3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes thats what we want to do. How do we do that?

Comment: We dont want to add another button what we are trying to do is when you click the drop down combo box it clears the previous data and shows the periods again.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion we are working on this in class and I am getting stuck on here trying to word the questions

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub dropdown_onChange (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles yourdropdown.SelectedIndexChanged
  PeriodDD.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```

...but I'm firing from the hip here...I'm not sure how you have this set up.

Kind Regards,

-sf